# Inherit css property from another property of a different class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to get the below to work?

```
.class1 {
 line-height:20px;
}

.class2 {
  height: class1.line-height;
}
```

I know that css variables would be the way to go but since it is in experimental phase, it would not be a suitable for our project. Is there any other way?

Comment: You need SASS or LESS instead.

Comment: This is why it's called "cascading"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Five years later...

> I know that css variables would be the way to go but since it is in experimental phase, it would not be a suitable for our project.

As it's 2021 (and no-one is using Internet Explorer 11 anymore, *phew*, and all the major browsers fully support <del>CSS Variables</del> CSS Custom Properties) so you *can* now use `var()`.

If you simply want to only define `20px` *once* to avoid repeating yourself in CSS, then set a custom-property on a *common ancestor* of both `.class1` and `.class2` elements: most people use `html` (or `html:root` or just `:root`) for this:

```
:root {
    --my-height: 20px;
}

.class1 {
    line-height: var(--my-height);
}

.class2 {
    height: var(--my-height);
}
```

---

Now, if you want `.class2` elements to "inherit" their `height:` from any ancestor `class1` elements instead of `<html>`, then this should work:

```css
:root {
    --my-height: 50px; /* Default value for .class2 elements which are not descendants of .class1` */
}

.class1 {
    --my-height: 20px; /* Redefining the value */
    line-height: var(--my-height);
}

.class2 {
    height: var(--my-height);
}
```

...or if you want *only* `.class2` descendants of `.class1` to use the value:

```css
:root {
}

.class1 {
    --my-height: 20px;
    line-height: var(--my-height);
}

.class1 .class2 {
    height: var(--my-height);
}
```

---

But you *probably* shouldn't be setting `line-height` anyway - doing-so is a sign that you're misusing `display: inline;` or `vertical-align:;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use dependencies like that in CSS without a preprocessor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). But you can apply more than one class to the HTML.....

`<div class="class1 class2"></div>`

In this case, `class1` would contain the line-height, then `class2` would contain any other properties you want to apply to that particular div.

Any similar properties between `class1` and `class2` would  allow `class2` to take precedence, since it's loaded after `class 1`, assuming the CSS hierarchy is logical.

For example:

```
.class1 { line-height: 1.3; background-color: red;}
.class2 { background-color: blue; }
```

The div would have a line-height of 1.3x and a background color of blue.

Answer (score 2):

yeah.. you can't use dependencies like that in CSS.
you have to use SASS or LESS..

you can do like this in SASS

```
.class1 {
     line-height:20px;
    }

.class2 {
   @extend.class1
}
```